# Chrome webrequest doesn't see POST data in requestBody

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am having a problem getting the POST data from a Facebook action.  When you submit a comment on FB it posts to this url: https://www.facebook.com/ufi/add/comment/?__pc=EXP1%3ADEFAULT
In the request, the post data for the post exists: 
Here is an example of the actual comment from the post data:

```
comment_text:test this is a test
```

When I try to access this through a Chrome Extension I can't seem to get this data.  I've tried parsing the requestBody, but it is empty.  I then tried to see if any of the other requestmethods would work, and I can't seem to find the data anywhere.

manifest.json:

```
{
"background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
 },
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Interaction Tracker",
"description": "Track social interactions by social site and customizable categories.",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [ "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "webNavigation", "tabs", "<all_urls>", "debugger" ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.method == "POST") {
        var fb_add_comment_regex = new RegExp(".*facebook\.com\/ufi\/add\/comment.*");
        if ( fb_add_comment_regex.test(details.url) ) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
            }
        }
  },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "requestBody"]
    );

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.method == "POST") {
        var fb_add_comment_regex = new RegExp(".*facebook\.com\/ufi\/add\/comment.*");
        if ( fb_add_comment_regex.test(details.url) ) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
            }
        }
  },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
    );


chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.method == "POST") {
        var fb_add_comment_regex = new RegExp(".*facebook\.com\/ufi\/add\/comment.*");
        if ( fb_add_comment_regex.test(details.url) ) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
            }
        }
  },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["requestHeaders"]
    );

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.method == "POST") {
        var fb_add_comment_regex = new RegExp(".*facebook\.com\/ufi\/add\/comment.*");
        if ( fb_add_comment_regex.test(details.url) ) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
            }
        }
  },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
    );

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.method == "POST") {
        var fb_add_comment_regex = new RegExp(".*facebook\.com\/ufi\/add\/comment.*");
        if ( fb_add_comment_regex.test(details.url) ) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
            }
        }
  },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
    );

chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.method == "POST") {
        var fb_add_comment_regex = new RegExp(".*facebook\.com\/ufi\/add\/comment.*");
        if ( fb_add_comment_regex.test(details.url) ) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
            }
        }
  },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["responseHeaders"]
    );

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.method == "POST") {
        var fb_add_comment_regex = new RegExp(".*facebook\.com\/ufi\/add\/comment.*");
        if ( fb_add_comment_regex.test(details.url) ) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
            }
        }
  },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["responseHeaders"]
    );

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.method == "POST") {
        var fb_add_comment_regex = new RegExp(".*facebook\.com\/ufi\/add\/comment.*");
        if ( fb_add_comment_regex.test(details.url) ) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
            }
        }
  },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["responseHeaders"]
    );
```

Below is the output from the console.log statements for each type of request:

onBeforeRequest

```
{
  "frameId": 0,
  "method": "POST",
  "parentFrameId": -1,
  "requestBody": {
    "raw": [
      {
        "bytes": {

        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "requestId": "6724",
  "tabId": 93,
  "timeStamp": 1444749653166.1,
  "type": "xmlhttprequest",
  "url": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/ufi\/add\/comment\/?__pc=EXP1%3ADEFAULT"
}
```

onBeforeSendHeaders

```
{
  "frameId": 0,
  "method": "POST",
  "parentFrameId": -1,
  "requestHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "Origin",
      "value": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id",
      "value": "AB63796C-002A-4670-8A56-547F8D13CA8C"
    },
    {
      "name": "User-Agent",
      "value": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/45.0.2454.101 Safari\/537.36"
    },
    {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "application\/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    {
      "name": "Accept",
      "value": "*\/*"
    },
    {
      "name": "Referer",
      "value": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/GrauZug?ref=br_rs"
    },
    {
      "name": "Accept-Encoding",
      "value": "gzip, deflate"
    },
    {
      "name": "Accept-Language",
      "value": "en-US,en;q=0.8"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cookie",
      "value": "datr=pvA2VDnTeMjGlWhVYRrnhBtO; lu=gh2TS-IuZkO-Ku-YhAzkiFIw; p=-2; c_user=100000720140344; fr=07LqqXcCamvBIa9Ww.AWU6e_qoHRglPj51gS-CF6uF-r8.BVY1Qk.DT.FYB.0.AWVvgvJA; xs=79%3A403i2b7V6bYSIA%3A2%3A1439311770%3A8344; csm=2; s=Aa4bsJIf94u-JaGr.BVyieb; presence=EDvF3EtimeF1444749507EuserFA21B00720140344A2EstateFDsb2F1444656454966Et2F_5b_5dElm2FnullEuct2F1444743344BEtrFnullEtwF2707054892EatF1444748467285G444749507665CEchFDp_5f1B00720140344F101CC; act=1444749649564%2F26"
    }
  ],
  "requestId": "6724",
  "tabId": 93,
  "timeStamp": 1444749653173.2,
  "type": "xmlhttprequest",
  "url": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/ufi\/add\/comment\/?__pc=EXP1%3ADEFAULT"
}
```

onSendHeaders

```
{
  "frameId": 0,
  "method": "POST",
  "parentFrameId": -1,
  "requestHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "Origin",
      "value": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id",
      "value": "AB63796C-002A-4670-8A56-547F8D13CA8C"
    },
    {
      "name": "User-Agent",
      "value": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/45.0.2454.101 Safari\/537.36"
    },
    {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "application\/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    {
      "name": "Accept",
      "value": "*\/*"
    },
    {
      "name": "Referer",
      "value": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/GrauZug?ref=br_rs"
    },
    {
      "name": "Accept-Encoding",
      "value": "gzip, deflate"
    },
    {
      "name": "Accept-Language",
      "value": "en-US,en;q=0.8"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cookie",
      "value": "datr=pvA2VDnTeMjGlWhVYRrnhBtO; lu=gh2TS-IuZkO-Ku-YhAzkiFIw; p=-2; c_user=100000720140344; fr=07LqqXcCamvBIa9Ww.AWU6e_qoHRglPj51gS-CF6uF-r8.BVY1Qk.DT.FYB.0.AWVvgvJA; xs=79%3A403i2b7V6bYSIA%3A2%3A1439311770%3A8344; csm=2; s=Aa4bsJIf94u-JaGr.BVyieb; presence=EDvF3EtimeF1444749507EuserFA21B00720140344A2EstateFDsb2F1444656454966Et2F_5b_5dElm2FnullEuct2F1444743344BEtrFnullEtwF2707054892EatF1444748467285G444749507665CEchFDp_5f1B00720140344F101CC; act=1444749649564%2F26"
    }
  ],
  "requestId": "6724",
  "tabId": 93,
  "timeStamp": 1444749653175.2,
  "type": "xmlhttprequest",
  "url": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/ufi\/add\/comment\/?__pc=EXP1%3ADEFAULT"
}
```

onHeadersReceived

```
{
  "frameId": 0,
  "method": "POST",
  "parentFrameId": -1,
  "requestId": "6724",
  "responseHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "status",
      "value": "200"
    },
    {
      "name": "cache-control",
      "value": "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    },
    {
      "name": "content-encoding",
      "value": "gzip"
    },
    {
      "name": "content-security-policy",
      "value": "default-src * data: blob:;script-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.akamaihd.net *.atlassolutions.com blob: chrome-extension:\/\/lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl;style-src * 'unsafe-inline';connect-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* *.akamaihd.net wss:\/\/*.facebook.com:* https:\/\/fb.scanandcleanlocal.com:* *.atlassolutions.com attachment.fbsbx.com 127.0.0.1:*;"
    },
    {
      "name": "content-type",
      "value": "application\/x-javascript; charset=utf-8"
    },
    {
      "name": "date",
      "value": "Tue, 13 Oct 2015 15:20:55 GMT"
    },
    {
      "name": "expires",
      "value": "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    },
    {
      "name": "pragma",
      "value": "no-cache"
    },
    {
      "name": "public-key-pins-report-only",
      "value": "max-age=500; pin-sha256=\"WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18=\"; pin-sha256=\"r\/mIkG3eEpVdm+u\/ko\/cwxzOMo1bk4TyHIlByibiA5E=\"; pin-sha256=\"q4PO2G2cbkZhZ82+JgmRUyGMoAeozA+BSXVXQWB8XWQ=\"; report-uri=\"http:\/\/reports.fb.com\/hpkp\/\""
    },
    {
      "name": "strict-transport-security",
      "value": "max-age=15552000; preload"
    },
    {
      "name": "vary",
      "value": "Accept-Encoding"
    },
    {
      "name": "x-content-type-options",
      "value": "nosniff"
    },
    {
      "name": "x-fb-debug",
      "value": "fd7Bt\/uIX2rLmngndhprmXlX3mTkZboQqcPSaw9kQt0aQUEfX3ikBMT1016i1c2RPbts9Jhbb0+bVGWPqk\/j7Q=="
    },
    {
      "name": "x-frame-options",
      "value": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "name": "x-xss-protection",
      "value": "0"
    }
  ],
  "statusCode": 200,
  "statusLine": "HTTP\/1.1 200 OK",
  "tabId": 93,
  "timeStamp": 1444749655679.6,
  "type": "xmlhttprequest",
  "url": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/ufi\/add\/comment\/?__pc=EXP1%3ADEFAULT"
}
```

onResponseStarted

```
{
  "frameId": 0,
  "fromCache": false,
  "ip": "31.13.93.3",
  "method": "POST",
  "parentFrameId": -1,
  "requestId": "6724",
  "responseHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "status",
      "value": "200"
    },
    {
      "name": "cache-control",
      "value": "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    },
    {
      "name": "content-encoding",
      "value": "gzip"
    },
    {
      "name": "content-security-policy",
      "value": "default-src * data: blob:;script-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.akamaihd.net *.atlassolutions.com blob: chrome-extension:\/\/lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl;style-src * 'unsafe-inline';connect-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* *.akamaihd.net wss:\/\/*.facebook.com:* https:\/\/fb.scanandcleanlocal.com:* *.atlassolutions.com attachment.fbsbx.com 127.0.0.1:*;"
    },
    {
      "name": "content-type",
      "value": "application\/x-javascript; charset=utf-8"
    },
    {
      "name": "date",
      "value": "Tue, 13 Oct 2015 15:20:55 GMT"
    },
    {
      "name": "expires",
      "value": "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    },
    {
      "name": "pragma",
      "value": "no-cache"
    },
    {
      "name": "public-key-pins-report-only",
      "value": "max-age=500; pin-sha256=\"WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18=\"; pin-sha256=\"r\/mIkG3eEpVdm+u\/ko\/cwxzOMo1bk4TyHIlByibiA5E=\"; pin-sha256=\"q4PO2G2cbkZhZ82+JgmRUyGMoAeozA+BSXVXQWB8XWQ=\"; report-uri=\"http:\/\/reports.fb.com\/hpkp\/\""
    },
    {
      "name": "strict-transport-security",
      "value": "max-age=15552000; preload"
    },
    {
      "name": "vary",
      "value": "Accept-Encoding"
    },
    {
      "name": "x-content-type-options",
      "value": "nosniff"
    },
    {
      "name": "x-fb-debug",
      "value": "fd7Bt\/uIX2rLmngndhprmXlX3mTkZboQqcPSaw9kQt0aQUEfX3ikBMT1016i1c2RPbts9Jhbb0+bVGWPqk\/j7Q=="
    },
    {
      "name": "x-frame-options",
      "value": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "name": "x-xss-protection",
      "value": "0"
    }
  ],
  "statusCode": 200,
  "statusLine": "HTTP\/1.1 200 OK",
  "tabId": 93,
  "timeStamp": 1444749655683.3,
  "type": "xmlhttprequest",
  "url": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/ufi\/add\/comment\/?__pc=EXP1%3ADEFAULT"
}
```

onCompleted

```
{
  "frameId": 0,
  "fromCache": false,
  "ip": "31.13.93.3",
  "method": "POST",
  "parentFrameId": -1,
  "requestId": "6724",
  "responseHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "status",
      "value": "200"
    },
    {
      "name": "cache-control",
      "value": "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    },
    {
      "name": "content-encoding",
      "value": "gzip"
    },
    {
      "name": "content-security-policy",
      "value": "default-src * data: blob:;script-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.akamaihd.net *.atlassolutions.com blob: chrome-extension:\/\/lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl;style-src * 'unsafe-inline';connect-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* *.akamaihd.net wss:\/\/*.facebook.com:* https:\/\/fb.scanandcleanlocal.com:* *.atlassolutions.com attachment.fbsbx.com 127.0.0.1:*;"
    },
    {
      "name": "content-type",
      "value": "application\/x-javascript; charset=utf-8"
    },
    {
      "name": "date",
      "value": "Tue, 13 Oct 2015 15:20:55 GMT"
    },
    {
      "name": "expires",
      "value": "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    },
    {
      "name": "pragma",
      "value": "no-cache"
    },
    {
      "name": "public-key-pins-report-only",
      "value": "max-age=500; pin-sha256=\"WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18=\"; pin-sha256=\"r\/mIkG3eEpVdm+u\/ko\/cwxzOMo1bk4TyHIlByibiA5E=\"; pin-sha256=\"q4PO2G2cbkZhZ82+JgmRUyGMoAeozA+BSXVXQWB8XWQ=\"; report-uri=\"http:\/\/reports.fb.com\/hpkp\/\""
    },
    {
      "name": "strict-transport-security",
      "value": "max-age=15552000; preload"
    },
    {
      "name": "vary",
      "value": "Accept-Encoding"
    },
    {
      "name": "x-content-type-options",
      "value": "nosniff"
    },
    {
      "name": "x-fb-debug",
      "value": "fd7Bt\/uIX2rLmngndhprmXlX3mTkZboQqcPSaw9kQt0aQUEfX3ikBMT1016i1c2RPbts9Jhbb0+bVGWPqk\/j7Q=="
    },
    {
      "name": "x-frame-options",
      "value": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "name": "x-xss-protection",
      "value": "0"
    }
  ],
  "statusCode": 200,
  "statusLine": "HTTP\/1.1 200 OK",
  "tabId": 93,
  "timeStamp": 1444749655684.2,
  "type": "xmlhttprequest",
  "url": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/ufi\/add\/comment\/?__pc=EXP1%3ADEFAULT"
}
```

Any other listener not listed above didn't have output.

Anyone have any idea here?

Comment: Is `requestBody` really empty, i.e. are all keys missing...?

Comment: "I've tried parsing the requestBody, but it is empty". Where's your code for that? How do you know it's empty?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is empty or if they keys are missing.  All I do know is that I am dumping the entire details, and this is what I get:   "requestBody": {
    "raw": [
      {
        "bytes": {

        }
      }
    ]
  }

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your console.log shows that `requestBody` is *not* empty.

You'll just have to parse the `raw` bytes:

> If the request method is PUT or POST, and the body is not already parsed in formData, then the unparsed request body elements are contained in this array.

For example if the posted data is a string then you can get its value in [`onBeforeRequest` listener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest):

```
var postedString = decodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,
                                      new Uint8Array(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes)));
```

There are many methods to decode the string depending on the encoding used by the site script.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the correct answer.  I didn't realize that there was data in the raw area.  I had tried to print that data to the console but didn't realize the method.

Comment: FYI, you seem to be missing a closing parenthesis at the end, +1 though

Comment: This can potentially truncate request bodies where raw has more than 1 entry. You need to account for every raw entry. Essentially convert each to a string and join them. Something like this `details.requestBody.raw.map(function(data) { return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(data.bytes)) }).join('')`

Answer (score 3):

Another reason why the request body might not be present is because extraInfoSpec must contain 'requestBody' as per below.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details)
    {
        console.log(details.requestBody);
    },
    {urls: ["https://myurlhere.com/*"]},
    ['requestBody']
);
```