# I'm catching chrome extension xhr requests but not getting the returned values

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm catching the Chrome extension xhr requests but not getting the returned values. I can see that the status is 200 in the value I received and it is complete. But I can't access the return value. How can I access the return value from the request?
[image]

```js
  chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function (details) {
            console.log(details)
           }, {urls: ['<all_urls>']});
```

Comment: Do it like retrieving JSON contents.     console.log(details.url);

Comment: I can get the url address, but not the return value from the request. I tried, but what I need is the file or json that returns the result of the request. I need to be able to access the responseText in the xhr request. I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52911475/15929287 i found this link but return values ​​are always error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome webrequest doesn't see POST data in requestBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106709/chrome-webrequest-doesnt-see-post-data-in-requestbody)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've tried every possible way but I can't read the value from an expired xhr request.