# How to get content (body) of chrome.webRequest?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

my background.js

```
const networkFilters = {
    urls: ["https://www.google.com/search*"],
};
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener((details) => {
        console.log(details.url);
        console.log('body', details.requestBody);
    },
    networkFilters,
    ['requestBody']
);
```

However the body is always empty.

I got this answer :
[Chrome extension to read HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939467/chrome-extension-to-read-http-response)

But it looks like it is 4 years old.

Comment: That answer still applies, nothing's changed since. See also [Chrome webrequest doesn't see POST data in requestBody](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33107811).